# generating many sequence(s)

Tags: r, loops, vector, counter, seq

I would like to generate following sequences:

```
myseq <- seq(0,0.1, by=0.0001)
myseq <- seq(0,0.2, by=0.0001)
myseq <- seq(0,0.3, by=0.0001)
.
.
. 
myseq <- seq(0,1, by=0.0001)
myseq <- seq(0.1,0.2, by=0.0001)
myseq <- seq(0.1,0.3, by=0.0001)
myseq <- seq(0.1,0.4, by=0.0001)
.
.
.
myseq <- seq(0.9,1, by=0.0001) # I want to stop here.
```

I tried with following code manually but my intuition does not seem to be correct here:

```
#Counters
from=0
to=0.1
a = seq(from, to, by=0.001)

#I execute following to check if my intuition is correct. 

from=case_when(to<=0.9 ~ from,
                 to==1 ~ from+0.1)
  
to=case_when(to<0.9 ~ to+0.1,
               to==1 ~ 1)
  
a = seq(from, to, by=0.0001)
```

Comment: How do you want to store all these sequences? In a list?

Comment: @AllanCameron yes I would like to store as list.

Answer (score 2):

Use `combn` to create a matrix of `seq`'s `from` and `to` parameters, and then apply them on `seq` using `mapply` to create the list of sequences.

```r
comb <- combn(seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), m = 2)
mapply(function(x, y) seq(x, y, by = 0.0001), comb[1,], comb[2,])
```